# Android: Onclick listener for EditText

Tags: android, onclick, android-edittext

Following is my code. When I click the EditText system doesn't trigger the intent, instead it brings up the keyboard on second click only it triggers the intent. How to make sure it happens on first click.

```
description.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Toast.makeText(sendingpage.this, description.getText(), 2000).show();
                Intent fullscreen = new Intent(sendingpage.this, ShowSummeryActivity.class);;
                startActivity(fullscreen);

            }
        });
```

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: I had the same issue due to android:focusable="true" and android:focusableInTouchMode="true" set somewhere in the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you get this behaviour, i got the same code and it works fine both on emulator and HTC device. Anyway you can hide the soft keyboard manually by using the `InputMethodManager`. Add this to your `onClick` method.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(description.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: I'm getting same behaviour in the emulator too :( I'm using Nexus S for dev. I updated the onclick with the code segment u gave and still keyboard invoked :(

Comment: Ok, another (more radical) option is to prevent showing soft keyboard in the whole window: `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);` Call it when the activity is created

Comment: Try to apply the `InputType` to your `EditText`: `EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);` (or by editing xml)

Comment: I'm gonna replace the edit_text with a button and will apply a image background that resembles EditText. That is how my iPhone colleque implemented it. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 6):

i had the same problem
**the solution is** (with warpzit comment help) **to add android:focusable="false" and android:focusableInTouchMode="false"**
this solved my issue easily

Answer (score 0):

you can use onTouchListener intead of onClickListener!!

```html
  description.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
            if (motionEvent.action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
               // you can set the intent here!!
            }
            false
        }
```

This code is in Kotlin you can change this code to Java.